# Why aren't Heroku syslog drains logging to rsyslogd?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, heroku

I'm having a problem using syslog drains as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging.

To summarize, I have an Ubuntu 10.04 instance on EC2 that is running `rsyslogd`.  I've also set up the security groups as they describe, and added a syslog drain using a command like `heroku drains:add syslog://host1.example.com:514`.

I can send messages from the Heroku console to my `rsyslogd` instance via `nc`.  I see them appear in the log file, so I know there isn't a firewall/security group issue.  However, Heroku does not seem to be forwarding log messages to the server that `heroku drains` lists.  I would expect to see HTTP requests, Rails messages, etc.

Is there something else I can try to do to figure this out?  I'm new to `rsyslogd`, so I could easily be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what I had done wrong, with the help of Heroku Support.  (Thanks guys!)

I had used the wrong security group name (`default` instead of `logplex`).  (Dynos run under `default`, so that's why `nc` worked.)

These are the appropriate values for the fields in the AWS Security Group web interface:

- Create a new rule: `Custom TCP rule`
- Port range: `514`
- Source: `098166147350/logplex` (NOTE: **not** `default`)

Answer (score 2):

My two cents here:

Notice that adding the port number (514) at the end of the drain URL is important. I initially though that the 'syslog://' prefix should suffice, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this.  One thing got me though.  I had to restart my app on heroku before it started writing to the new drains.  (after I tried so many other things!)

Comment: Happy it helped!  :)  For what it's worth, this may be more appropriate as a comment on my answer rather than a standalone answer itself.

Comment: well, it is another answer to the question.  but hairs splitting.  :)     anyway, happy i got it working - also installed splunk which seems to be pretty fantastic to digest the logs.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying that you had to do what my answer was, in addition to your own...  My misunderstanding.  :)